# Is there a way to delete users for your Facebook Application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There is documentation for test users in the Facebook Developer online documentation but how do you delete actual users where the application doesn't show in their app list anymore?  This is with the knowledge of the `access_token` and `facebook_user_id`.

Used to delete Test Users:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/893450345999?method=delete&access_token=A2ADI1YMySweBABBGrWPNwKMlubZA5ZCrQbxwhtlEd9FIQUrOVjsGD3mnIWEbUhzDz7dkuBekMFdHvjvJ9CZAU7EMSSaZBsgN60FkMCi3AAZDZD
```

Running the test user link produces the following error:

```
"error": {
      "message": "(#100) Can only call this method on valid test users for your app",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You seek for application de-authorization:

> You can de-authorize an application or revoke a specific extended permissions on behalf of a user by issuing an HTTP DELETE request to PROFILE_ID/permissions with a user access_token for that app.
>
> *permission* - The permission you wish to revoke. If you don't specify a permission then this will **de-authorize the application completely**.

To achieve this issue request to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?method=delete&access_token=...
```

Once application de-authorized it will not appear in the list of user's applications.

**Update December 2021**

Follow the reference for [Requesting & Revoking Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking#revoking):

To remove single permission issue a `DELETE` request to `/{user-id}/permissions/{permission-name}` passing **user access token** or an **app access token**

To de-authorize an app completely issue similar request to the `/{user-id}/permissions` endpoint

Comment: It there a way to do this for ALL users, without deleting the app itself?

Comment: If I have many permissions, do I need loop through all of those, and DELETE all of them in order for my app to no longer appear ?

Comment: What If I do not have the user access token? What token should I use?

Comment: @FedericoSchiocchet I've updated my answer to provide more details. Use your application access token to revoke permissions if you don't have the user access token

Answer (score 5):

Real users 'delete' themselves from your app when they remove your app from their account, you don't have to do anything.

If you would like to know when users de-authorize your app like this, you can specify a *Deauthorize Callback URL* in your app's settings. As described in the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/:

> Upon app removal we will send an HTTP POST request containing a single parameter, signed_request, which, once decoded, will yield a JSON object containing the user_id of the user who just deauthorized your app. You will not receive an user access token in this request and all existing user access tokens that were previously issued on behalf of that user will become invalid.

**UPDATE**: To remove your own app from the user's authorized applications, issue an HTTP DELETE to `https://graph.facebook.com/[userid]/permissions?access_token=...` as per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/.

Typically Graph API calls also support doing an HTTP POST with an extra parameter, `method=DELETE`, in case DELETE calls are not possible/supported.

Comment: I want to be able to allow the user to remove the application from within my website.  If you've used pinterest you'll see that on a user's edit user settings page they can link/unlink their facebook app on their website, not on facebook.com. This removes the pinterest application entirely from the user's installed facebook applications list.

Answer (score 0):

To do it:

1. You must have the user access token.
2. Visit https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ and debug the user access token.
3. Copy App-Scoped User ID
4. Via API call HTTP DELETE to [https://graph.facebook.com/[App-Scoped](https://graph.facebook.com/%5BApp-Scoped) User ID]/permissions?method=delete&access_token=[YOUR-APP-ACCESS-TOKEN]