# Firebase Facebook Authentication - re-request permissions

Tags: facebook, authentication, permissions, firebase

When a user authenticates with Facebook, they are given the option to decline permissions that are asked.

Facebook allows us to re-ask the permission by adding this: auth_type: 'rerequest' (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0#re-asking-declined-permissions)

I can't find a way to re-request permissions that were initially denied using Firebase.

Does anyone know how?

Jarrod

Comment: We don't do anything special when making the request to Facebook on our backend. So we unfortunately don't provide this feature at the moment. This is actually the first I'm hearing of it and must be a somewhat new feature (I'm guessing since they allowed for partial acceptance of permissions). If we get enough people asking about this, we will look into implementing it. I'm not really sure exactly it would fit into our current workflow though.

Comment: One way to work around this would be to authenticate with Facebook OAuth directly, and pass the resulting token into Firebase's authWithOAuthToken().

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE: Best workaround**

*Facebook Login*: User clicks login with Facebook button and denies a required permission or chooses "Not Now" in Facebook popup login window. User get's logged into your website, but you want to ensure the user authorizes your required permissions.

In your signInSuccess callback: You should immediately delete your user from your Facebook app if user signs in and denies your permissions.

Then immediately sign out your user; forcing another login attempt.

User will try to login again and Facebook will request permissions again. This continues until user permits or gives up. Here's what I'm running with.

```
var usersFacebookToken = credential.accessToken;
var fbPermissionsUrl = `https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=${usersFacebookToken}`

$http.get(fbPermissionsUrl)
    .then(function(response) {
        let facebookPerms = response.data.data;

        facebookPerms.forEach(function(item) {
            if (item.permission === 'email' && item.status === 'declined' || item.permission === 'user_posts' && item.status === 'declined') {
                console.log(`${item.permission} denied`)
                    // remove user from my facebook app

                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?method=delete&access_token=${fbUserAccessToken}`
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    // this user has been deleted from the FACEBOOK APP
                    // when user does Facebook login/signup again
                    // then permissions will be requested again
                    return true;

                }, function errorCallback(error) {
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                    console.error(error)
                });

                alert("Email and user posts history are required")
                delete $scope.currentUser;
                firebase.auth().signOut();
            }
        })

    });
```

**Previous**

I've implemented customParameters, and they DO get passed to Facebook, but the user will NOT be prompted again to allow permissions even while using `auth_type: 'reauthenticate' or auth_type: 'rerequest'`.

I'm going to look into DELETEing the user from my Facebook App, then prompt for login again. In referencing to this thread: [Is there a way to delete users for your Facebook Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710844/is-there-a-way-to-delete-users-for-your-facebook-application)
Until then...

**Workaround**: Have the user delete your App registered with Facebook and then login on your site again. Then the user will be prompted to authorize whatever permissions your request through scope.

Direct the user here, have them find your app, then click Remove App in the tiny font at the bottom of the modal:
https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

**This is the reference to passing customParameters**:
Check the link on Github: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#configure-oauth-providers

```
    {
  provider: firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
  scopes: [
    'public_profile',
    'email',
    'user_likes',
    'user_friends'
  ],
  customParameters: {
    // Forces password re-entry.
    auth_type: 'reauthenticate'
  }
},
```

**Here is how I'm instructing my users to delete my App on Facebook**

1. Step 1 - Go to this link
2. Step 2 - Find the app TEFL.pro
3. Step 3 - Click Remove App at the bottom of the modal
4. Step 4 - Login with Facebook again

Yes, I'm aware that a user isn't going to do this, but until FirebaseUI is rerequesting permissions properly, I'm going this route. If I loose a user who didn't authorize the required permissions from the start, then so be it. I'm going with the *Pareto principle* here.

[image: Facebook List of Apps]

[image: Click remove app]

Answer (score 0):

I now it's no an answer but...
Just stumble on this too, if the user decline giving his email the app enters on a loop, doing the login without the email and doesn't give the user a chance to user allow the information. 
It is a pretty deficiency on firebase facebook oauth in my point. I'm going to develop my app hoping that none of the users think in decline the email information.

Firebase facebook oauth must include support for auth_type=rerequest in order to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom provider values with `setCustomParameters`. In this case, what you want to do is invoke it like the below to rerequest the permissions.

```
provider.setCustomParameters({
  auth_type: 'rerequest'
});
```

Link to the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login