# How to block Facebook webhook calls for app specific users?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-comments, facebook-events, facebook-webhooks

We have a Facebook app that manages user business pages, we are using webhooks to subscribe to **'feed'** event for access comments. Our application has **7 days free** trial after that the account becomes **inactive and may be deleted** from our database. But since the user didn't delete our app from his current apps in Facebook, we

> still getting his events through webhooks

, this way we are keep getting calls from webhook for all our old deleted users. I couldn't find any way to **unsubscribe webhook calls for a specific user** of the app. Like the way user deletes app permissions from his Facebook dashboard, is there a way an app can also make a user invalid for that app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710844/is-there-a-way-to-delete-users-for-your-facebook-application (?)

Comment: This is not a duplicate IMO but I can't answer it since it is marked as a duplicate.